# screenshot listener in selenium with TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I have a testcase that will invoke the driver as a non static variable. I also have added screenshot listener in my test case. When the test case fails The control is automatically sent to the screenshot listener, however since my driver is a NON-STATIC variable it could not be accessed in the screenshot listener. So I get nullpointer exception.

To solve this I created a simple base test class with help of stackoverflow like below and extend it in each testclass

```html
public asbtract baseTest() {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
            return driver;
}

    @BeforeMethod
    public void createDriver() {
            Webdriver driver=XXXXDriver();
    }

    @AfterMethod
        public void tearDownDriver() {
        if (driver != null)
        {
                try
                {
                    driver.quit();
                }
                catch (WebDriverException e) {
                    System.out.println("***** CAUGHT EXCEPTION IN DRIVER TEARDOWN *****");
                    System.out.println(e);
                }

        }
    }
```

In my listener, I access the base class as follows

```js
public class ScreenshotListener extends TestListenerAdapter {
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result)
{
        Object currentClass = result.getInstance();
        WebDriver webDriver = ((baseTest) currentClass).getDriver();

        if (webDriver != null)
        {

           File f = ((TakesScreenshot) webDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

           //etc.
        }
}
```

My test class looks like this

```js
@Listeners(value = FailureReport.class)
public class LoginTest extends baseTest{

    Login login = new Login(getDriver());
    
    @Test(description = "Verify Expand the Menu", priority = 0)
    public void navigateloginpage() {
        login.expandMenuScreenLogin();
        login.navigateLoginPage();
    }

    @Test(description = "User login Sucessfully", priority = 1)
    public void successLogin() {
        login.login();
    }
```

When I run this it gives me the error

```html
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: com.fbf.automation.tests.LoginTest
 at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
 at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
 at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
 at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:548)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:745)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1359)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
 at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
 at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:38)
 at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
 at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
 at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
 at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:302)
 at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:45)
 at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Later when I changed my test class as follows it ran correctly

```js
@Listeners(value = FailureReport.class)
    public class LoginTest extends baseTest{

        Login login;
        
        @Test(description = "Verify Expand the Menu", priority = 0)
        public void navigateloginpage() {
            login = new Login(getDriver());
            login.expandMenuScreenLogin();
            login.navigateLoginPage();
        }

        @Test(description = "User login Sucessfully", priority = 1)
        public void successLogin() {
            login.login();
        }
```

Isn't it possible to declare the code

```js
login = new Login(getDriver());
```

outside @test method  rather than writing it inside the @test method. Or are there anyother alternative ways I can call the above code

Comment: Is not possible cause it would call this on instantiation of the object but the driver is instantiated on @before method which is called after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create Login object inside  @BeforeClass method

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)

public void setUp() throws Exception {
    login = new Login(getDriver());
}
```